# How dynamically change feature file path in cucumber testrun command?

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, cucumber, automated-tests

I'm working now with cucumber project and I face with a small problem and need help)

I run some feature using commend:

`cucumber features/path_to_feature/some_feature.feature`

How can I dynamically change `some_feature.feature` to `other_feature.feature`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what exactly you are looking for. 
If you are running the command from the command line interface, you can wrap your execution commands in a standalone ruby / shell script and pass the feature names dynamically.
OR
You could also use the cucumber config file (cucumber.yml) if you want to execute particular feature files.